# Using std::thread for send and recive data from TCP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, tcpclient

I'm developing a TCP socket client. I am trying to write a client that have individual thread for send and receive data. but when I use thread, get a runtime error.

The process goes like this:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include "TCPConnection.h"

SOCKET sock;

void SendRecive(SOCKET *isock) {
    // Do-While loop to send and recive data
    char buf[4096];

    while (true) {
        // Prompt the user for some text
        cout << "> ";
        // Wait for response
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
        auto byteRecived = recv(*isock, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (byteRecived <= 0) continue;
        // Echo response to console
        cout << "SERVER> " << string(buf, 0, byteRecived) << endl;
    }
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    TCPConnection tcpconn("192.168.1.4", 7705, &sock);
    SendRecive(&sock);
    return 0;
}
```

TCPConnection.h:

```
//
// Created by Hamed on 8/21/2021.
//

#ifndef TCPCLIENT_TCPCONNECTION_H
#define TCPCLIENT_TCPCONNECTION_H

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

class TCPConnection {
public:
    SOCKET *isock;
    TCPConnection(string ServerIPAddress, int ServerPort, SOCKET *sock);
    ~TCPConnection();
};

#endif //TCPCLIENT_TCPCONNECTION_H
```

TCPConnection.cpp:

```
#include "TCPConnection.h"

TCPConnection::TCPConnection(string ServerIPAddress, int ServerPort, SOCKET *sock) {
    // Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data{};
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0) {
        cerr << "Can't start winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create socket
    *sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (*sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Fill in a hint structure
    sockaddr_in hint{};
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(ServerPort);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ServerIPAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    // connect to server
    int connResult = connect(*sock, (sockaddr *) &hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(*sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    isock = sock;
}



TCPConnection::~TCPConnection() {
    // Gracefully close down everything
    closesocket(*isock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

this code working properly but when I change "main.cpp" to use thread like this:

```
int main() {
    TCPConnection tcpconn("192.168.1.4", 7705, &sock);    
    thread DoRunTCPRecive(SendRecive,&sock);
    return 0;
}
```

I get "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" debug error when runing app.

[image]

**Update:**
Actually I want to have a function for send and have another function for receive data . but when I use join, my code stay on current function and I can't run another code after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should **join** the thread after create it

```cpp
    thread DoRunTCPRecive(SendRecive,&sock);
    DoRunTCPRecive.join()
```

Comment: I want to run another function alongside this fuction. actualy I want to have a function for send and have another function for receive data . but when I use join, my code stay on this line.

Comment: you mean you want send data in main thread?right?

Comment: No, I want to have two thread. one of them sending data and second thread receive data.

Comment: then you can do like this    thread DoRunTCPRecive(SendRecive,&sock); thread DoRunTCPSend(...); DoRunTCPRecive.join();DoRunTCPSend.join();

Comment: I do that. but my app stay  in  first join line "DoRunTCPRecive.join();"

Comment: that's right,cause the main thread is stay in first join,then you should let you app send some data to server,the server should return you some data (it's up to the server app's implementation) ,as a tcpclient ,usually client is the first one to send data.when you send data,and server return some data ,you thread **DoRunTCPRecive** should turn to active

Comment: @user3123721 Whenever you have a thread, you need to either wait for it to finish (with join) or not wait for it to finish (with detach)

Comment: Thanks. "detach" helped me.

Comment: Calling `join()` immediately after creating a new `thread` is useless, you may as well just call the function directly. Otherwise, yes, you need to `detach()` the thread instead.